# simple css3 animation is not smooth on safari and iPad UIWebView

Tags: ios, css

I am trying move a block of text using css3 animation. The animation is not smooth on safari and iPad UIWebview.  Here is the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/sur2/UKVQ2/) . Is there a way to make it lot smoother? It is more noticeable when I animate an image. I have used different timing function but still it is not smooth.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css"> 
div
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;

    -webkit-animation-name: mymove;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;  

}


@-webkit-keyframes mymove 
{
    from {left:0px;}
    to {left:200px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div>Move this block</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try to "force hardware acceleration" by adding -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) on the animated div

Try it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/aHWzN/

Update:
You can now use will-change to ensure smoother animations: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change

```
.foo {will-change: left}
```

Answer (score 2):

It has to do what composite layer that minimizes repaints. You can turn this on in about:flags in Chrome to see composite layers, called "Composited render layer borders."

When you use -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0) it often "kicks" it into composite layer. It also prepares it for animations.

For instance, if you have an image carousel, if you are animating the images, first put -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); on the img.

But that alone won't fix your animation flickering in iPad.

By specifying the timing function, it better handles the animation and you will have smooth results.

-webkit-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1.0); is easing in and out.

Yesterday, I made a simple sliding image carousel that works smoothly on iPad 1. https://github.com/grandecomplex/imagecarousel

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at my coworker's blog post. He discusses iOS animation performance in depth along with a video showing the performance differences between iOS versions.  http://uncorkedstudios.com/2011/11/18/animation-performance-disparity-on-ios/